# How to get wall structure from Autodesk Forge metadata

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to get model's metadata from SQLite database, as described here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer

Walls have multiple layers, but i can't get layers from database. First i get an wall-object by `id`:

```
SELECT i.id, a.name, v.value FROM _objects_eav e
LEFT JOIN _objects_id i ON e.entity_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN _objects_attr a ON e.attribute_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN _objects_val v ON e.value_id = v.id
where i.id=3586
ORDER BY name
```

Result:

```
3586    Area    12.5511
3586    Base Constraint L03
3586    Base Extension Distance 0.0
3586    Base Offset -80.0
3586    Base is Attached    0.0
3586    Category    Revit Стены
3586    CategoryId  -2000011
3586    Comments    Панели KMEW Фиот
3586    Enable Analytical Model 1
3586    Image   <Нет>
3586    Length  7625.00000000001
3586    Level   4
3586    Location Line   Чистовая поверхность: Наружная
3586    Mark    
3586    Phase Created   Проект
3586    Phase Demolished    Нет
3586    Rebar Cover - Exterior Face Сетка армирования 1 <25 мм>
3586    Rebar Cover - Interior Face Сетка армирования 1 <25 мм>
3586    Rebar Cover - Other Faces   Сетка армирования 1 <25 мм>
3586    Related to Mass 0.0
3586    Room Bounding   1
3586    Structural  1
3586    Structural Usage    Несущая
3586    Top Constraint  До уровня: L04
3586    Top Extension Distance  0.0
3586    Top Offset  500
3586    Top is Attached 0.0
3586    Type Name   Наружняя стена кирпич - 380 мм+утеплитель100мм+ крепление 50 мм+ панель 20мм
3586    Unconnected Height  2030.0
3586    Volume  6.90310500000002
3586    instanceof_objid    2338
3586    name    Базовая стена [584120]
3586    parent  2339
3586    viewable_in ad9ff762-0bef-4ca0-8be5-fd3793dbf337-000358db
3586    viewable_in c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-0013464c
```

Then i get type information of the object by `instanceof_objid`:

```
where i.id=2338
```

Result:

```
2338    Absorptance 0.1
2338    Assembly Code   
2338    Assembly Description    
2338    Coarse Scale Fill Color 128
2338    Coarse Scale Fill Pattern   <Сплошная заливка>
2338    Cost    0.0
2338    Description 
2338    Fire Rating 
2338    Function    Внутренние слои
2338    Heat Transfer Coefficient (U)   0.0
2338    Keynote 
2338    Manufacturer    
2338    Model   
2338    Roughness   1
2338    Structural Material Кирпич - полуторный
2338    Structure   
2338    Thermal Mass    0.0
2338    Thermal Resistance (R)  0.0
2338    Type Comments   
2338    Type Image  <Нет>
2338    Type Mark   
2338    URL 
2338    Width   550
2338    Wrapping at Ends    Нет
2338    Wrapping at Inserts Нет
2338    Марка   
2338    Огнестойкость
```

Field `Structure` is empty string. How to get structure info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal wall structure is pretty BIM specific data, only of interest in the architectural and structural domains.

The Forge viewer is a completely generic viewer, suitable for all domains, including architecture, infrastructure, mechanical and many others.

The preparation and translation of the seed CAD model for the Forge environment includes stripping of all domain-specific data for optimisation and efficient streaming purposes.

Some domain specific data that is not of general interest to all domains is therefore lost in the process of translating the seed CAD file to the optimised Forge data format.

Afaik, this includes the internal compound layer wall structure that you request.

Therefore, to access and extract this data, you will need access to the original RVT BIM model.

The wall compound layer can be read, analysed and exported either using the Revit API on the Windows desktop or the [Forge Design Automation API for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page).