# Can we access the data used by Revit Material Takeoff from forge viewer API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api

Can we access the data used by Revit Material Takeoff from forge viewer API?

For example, I have a wall (1 element) that have 2 layers:

[image]

And now I want to get the volume for each layer from BIM360 viewer API, in the same way I can in Revit Material takeoff.

[image]

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always remember that the Forge viewer and environment is completely generic and not tailored towards any specific domain or functionality.

In the case of an architectural wall, Forge is mainly interested in displaying the entire wall element and managing the parameters and properties directly associated with that top-level element.

The material takeoff information you are interested in is part of the wall's internal compound structure. Managing and accessing that information is domain specific, architectural and structural, and thus beyond the scope of the Forge viewer.

I rather doubt that that information is accessible in Forge or the BIM360 viewer.

So, it will not be available via the model derivative API either.

However, you can certainly access this data via the Forge Design Automation for Revit API.

The details of such an approach are discussed in a previous thread
on [how to get wall structure from Autodesk Forge metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470692/how-to-get-wall-structure-from-autodesk-forge-metadata/68480362#68480362).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I understand why it make sense that it is not there, I guess I was optimistic.
Thank you,